# drop-and-create-tables drops too easily

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, jpql, toplink

I just switched my persistence.xml from

```
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
```

to

```
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

and now data persists between application runs, as I would expect.  However, this isn't quite the way I would expect this setting to work.  Shouldn't drop-and-create only create when the table is missing or mismatched?

I'm just wondering whether this is standard, or perhaps an indication that I'm not using JPA correctly, that the table gets nuked too easily when drop-and-create is set.

Comment: Drop-create is great for integration tests and that's basically its purpose.

Comment: ah, that explains the purpose!  makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is intended behaviour.

`create-tables` will only attempt to create tables, if the table already exists then it will not be dropped or replaced, the existing table will be used. This does *not* check if the table matches the one you try to create - just if a table with the given name exists. If your scheme changes you'll have to drop the table manually (or through another machanism) so it's newly created the next time.

`drop-and-create-tables` will first drop the existing table, and then create the new table. Note that this will loose all of the data in the tables when they are dropped.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick reply and confirmation that this is the intended behavior.  I don't think it's the **correct** behavior, but that's just my opinion.  Anyhow, good to know, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think your observations are correct. At least I had the same problems. It would be great if there were another option with your described behaviour.

Comment: Marko Topolnik explains in a comment on the question that the purpose is for integration tests.